# Integration of a function with 2 variables

Tags: calculus, integration

Suppose that $\ u(x, t)$ is continuous, together with its first and second partial derivatives;
suppose that u and its first partial derivatives are periodic in x of period 1, and
suppose that $\ u_{tt} = u_{xx}$ . Prove that

$\ A(t)=\frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{1} (u_t^2(x,t) +u_x^2(x,t))dx $ is a constant, indepdent of t.

I tried to show $\ A'(t) = 0$

so differentiate both sides, I got

$\ \frac{d}{dt} A(t) = \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{1} (2u_t u_{tt} + 2u_x u_{xt} )dx  = \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{1} (2u_t u_{xx} + 2u_x u_{xt} )dx $

Then I am stuck on the integration, because $\ u_t$ can have $\ x$ in it, can anyone help? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost there. Keep going with the fact that $u_x, u_t$ are periodic in $x$ with period 1 :)
\begin{align*}
\int(u_tu_{xx}+u_xu_{xt})dx &= \int u_tu_{xx} dx + \int u_xu_{xt}dx\\
&= \int u_tu_{xx} dx + \int u_xdu_t\\
&= \int u_tu_{xx} dx + \left(u_xu_t|_{x=0}^1 - \int u_t du_x\right)\\
&= \int u_tu_{xx} dx + 0 -  \int u_t u_{xx}dx\\
&= 0
\end{align*}
where line 1 to 2 is u-substition, and line 2 to 3 is integration by parts.